# Pixel & Tonic Field Pack 2.x :all_options and outputting when a checkbox is not selected

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack, pt-checkboxes

I have a template on a site being updated from EE 2.5.5 to EE 2.7.3 and during the update I've upgraded to the latest Field Pack 2.1.1.

My template includes use of a Field Pack - Checkboxes field and relies on the :all_options capability available in Field Pack 1.

Consequently it now fails because I belatedly see there is no mention of `:all_options` in the docs for Field Pack 2!

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/checkboxes/tags.html

I'm using my checkbox series to output a table so it's critical I can output *something* for each option regardless of whether it is selected or not.

For example, here's some of the code I had that was working before…

```
{grade_ff:all_options}
  {if '{selected}' == ""}<td class="{option_name}"></td>
  {if:else}<td class="{option_name} y">Yes</td>{/if}
{/grade_ff:all_options}
```

So unless I've missed something I now have to have a line of code **for each of my options explicitly**…

```
<td class="foo{if '{grade_ff:selected option="foo"}'} y">Yes{if:else}">{/if}</td>
<td class="bar{if '{grade_ff:selected option="bar"}'} y">Yes{if:else}">{/if}</td>
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:all_options` tag pair was actually removed [removed](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/pt_field_pack/commit/757754cbd0c8a975c7843f4dd78af886b80da9f9) two years ago, well before Field Pack 2.0 came out.

We removed it because EE doesn’t parse tags for fields that don’t have any data; it just removes them. And 99% of the time, people used the `:all_options` tag pair in cases where they would expect the options to appear regardless of whether a checkbox was checked or not, etc.. So it led to a lot of confusion when the options would randomly not appear for certain entries.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I had no idea it had been removed so long :$ It was darned useful though for constructing a table where the output of an empty cell is as important as the output of a cell with content, where both derive from a set of attribute statuses. Not sure now how to achieve that as elegantly as I was doing :(

Comment: Though I have got my template working again using the explicit verbose approach cited above.

Comment: We might consider adding a plugin that would let you get them via {exp:fieldpack:all_options} or something.

Comment: That would be nice :)